# JS or PHP Add Leading Zero to Decimals

Tags: php, javascript, formatting, decimal

I have a form that I'm trying to automatically enforce decimals in some of the input fields. Basically I would like for the users to not worry about format, but simply have the fields format themselves onBlur.

Here are a few examples of what I'm hoping to achieve:

1.) If a user enters "0.95" nothing is done, because this is the ultimate format I'm going for in the end.

2.) If a user enters ".95" I would like for the field onBlur to change to the above format "0.95". (likewise if they enter ".9" etc)

I have been scouring around on the internet all night long looking for a solution, so this is my last resort! Any help and feedback I can get would be more than appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nice and concise:

```
function blurFormatDecimal (e) {
    var val = isFinite(this.value) ? +this.value : 0;
    this.value = val.toFixed(2);
}
myInput.onblur = blurFormatDecimal;
```

Use `isFinite()` instead of `!isNaN()` because `isNaN("Infinity")` returns `false`, but you certainly don't want to accept `"Infinity"` as valid input.

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/NjeQD/

Comment: Thanks gilly!! That did the trick! Works with flying colors. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would do it:

```
document.getElementById('amount').onblur = function() {
    if(this.value && !isNaN(this.value)) {        
        this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
    } else {
        this.value = 0;
    }
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DYs7Y/1/)

Comment: [`parseFloat("Infinity").toFixed(2)`](http://jsfiddle.net/DYs7Y/2/) returns `"Infinity"`.  And [handling `"0"`](http://jsfiddle.net/DYs7Y/4/) returns `"0.00"`, which is inconsistent with [handling a non-numeric string](http://jsfiddle.net/DYs7Y/3/) (returns `"0"` without any decimal points).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this with PHP try:
`$formattedAmount = sprintf("%05.2f",$amount);`

Answer (score -1):

Here is the php solution:

```
$formattedAmount = sprintf("%01.2f",$amount);
```